# Covariates in correlation?

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I'm not sure if this is a question for `stackoverflow`, or `crossvalidated`.

I'm looking for away to include covariate measures when calculating the correlation between two measures. For example, Lets say I have 100 samples, for which I have two measurements, `x` and `y`. Now lets say I also have a third measure, a covariate (lets say `age`). I want to measure the correlation between `x` and `y`, but I also want to ignore any of that correlation that comes from the covariate, `age`.

If I'm fitting a linear model, I could simply add the term to the model:

```
lm(y~x+age)
```

I know you can't calculate correlation with this kind of model in `R` (using `~`).

So I want to know:

1. Does what I'm asking even make sense to do? I suspect it may not.
2. If it does, what R packages should I be using?

Comment: In other words what you are trying to do: if variable _x_ can be partially explained (fit) by variable _z_ (`age`), then exclude the component of _x_ explained by _z_ before fitting variable _y_ with _x_. Probably a question for **crossvalidated**.

Comment: yes, crossvalidated...hopefully it just gets migrated and I don't need to rewrite my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking for a semipartial correlation. You want the correlation between x and y partialling out the correlation between x and z. You need to read about [partial and semipartial correlations](http://luna.cas.usf.edu/~mbrannic/files/regression/Partial.html).

The ppcor package in R will then help you with the calculations.